# Capture fails in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using GNU Emacs 23.1.1 with org-mode version 7.7
I want to use `C-c c` t to capture a task and send it to `~/todo.org` as defined in the `org-capture-template` below. On pressing `C-c c`, the `Org Select` buffer opens but when I hit `t`, I get the error message `Capture abort: (void-function nil)` and nothing gets written to `todo.org`. The relevant lines from my `.emacs` are shown below. Please help me fix this.

```
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)

(setq org-directory "~/")

(setq org-capture-templates

(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/todo.org" "Tasks")
             "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")

("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/journal.org")
             "* %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

Comment: I'm using Emacs 24.4.1 with Org-mode 8.2.10. I had the same problem with my `org-capture`. I also followed the instructions below, but with the same result, as you commented then, more than five years ago. Did you found any solution in this time? If so, could you add an entry to explain how did you fix it, please? Thank you.

Comment: I don't remember finding a solution at that time. However, with org-mode 8.3.1, emacs 24.3.1 the following settings work. So you may want to upgrade org-mode.    
  <pre>  (setq org-capture-templates '(("t" "Todo" entry
                              (file+headline "~/org/todo.org" "Tasks")
                              "* TODO %^{Brief Description}" :prepend t)
                             ("e" "Email Todo" entry
                              (file+headline "~/org/todo.org" "Tasks")
                              "* TODO %:subject\n%a\n%?Added: %U\n" :prepend t)
      )) <code>

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote your list of capture templates.  If you change the relevant section as follows it should work.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote 
       (("t" "TODO" entry
        [...]
        "* %?\nEntered on %U\n %i\n %a"))))
```

Make sure you remember to include the closing `)` at the end or you'll end up with unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion by modifying the line as follows, but I get the same error message as before, unfortunately. So something else is broken, in addition to this.
(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote 
       (("t" "TODO" entry
        [...]
        "* %?\nEntered on %U\n %i\n %a"))))

Comment: Did you make sure to re-evaluate `org-capture-templates` after adding `(quote [...])` ?  I just took your original code, added wrapped the templates in `(quote )` and evaluated it without any trouble. If you evaluate the SEXP with `C-x e` does it give you an error? (Also try using org-capture again after doing so)

Comment: (setq org-capture-templates
      (quote 
       (("t" "TODO" entry
        [...]
        "* %?\nEntered on %U\n %i\n %a"))))

Comment: Sorry I messed up previous comment. Here is the correct one.Yes, I checked with C-x e to make sure that the expression looks correct. I also restarted emacs and then used C-h v to confirm that the org-capture-templates's value is as shown below. The capture buffer does show the t and j options so this seems to be working. But unfortunately, I still get the initial error message.
(("t" "Todo" entry  (file+headline "~/todo.org" "Tasks")
  "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")

 ("j" "Journal" entry  (file+datetree "~/journal.org")
  "* %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a"))

Comment: I was going to suggest you ask on the mailing list about this because the issue is somewhere other than your capture template, however I see that you did so this morning already.